# Notice: Array to string conversion after upgrade php to version 5.6

Tags: php, textarea

I'm trying to display textarea and im getting an error at line 114. 
The notify is like this:

C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content/plugins/options.php on line 114

My code is like this

```
 <?php
 function mistic_textarea($value,$attr){
 global $mistic_options,$wpdb;

            <li class="type-<?php echo ($value['type']);?>" id="container-<?php echo ($value['id']);?>">
                <fieldset class="title">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <label for="<?php echo ($value['id']); ?>"><?php echo ($value['name']); ?></label>
                        <?php if($value['desc']): ?><kbd><?php echo ($value['desc']); ?></kbd><?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="data">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <textarea name="<?php echo ($value['id']); ?>" id="<?php echo ($value['id']); ?>" <?php echo ($attr); ?>><?php if(isset($mistic_options->$value['id'])): echo ($mistic_options->$value['id']); else: echo ($value['value']); endif;?></textarea>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>
  }              
 ?>
```

And line 114 is :

```
 <textarea name="<?php echo ($value['id']); ?>" id="<?php echo ($value['id']); ?>" <?php echo ($attr); ?>><?php if(isset($up_options->$value['id'])): echo ($up_options->$value['id']); else: echo ($value['value']); endif;?></textarea>
```

Can anyone help me?  I'm pretty new to PHP.

Thank for any kind of helps.

Comment: Please provide var_dump of $value and $attr

Comment: @b0ne In which area? Sorry I am new on php

Comment: `var_dump($value);var_dump($attr);` provide these values. put it before `function mistic_textarea($value,$attr){` and see the ouptput

Comment: Place this code, and edit your question with the values printed on the screen. http://pastebin.com/m1DWpF5h

Comment: @b0ne Here the values printed on my screen array(6) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Main Text for 404" ["desc"]=> string(60) "Enter some texts for your users so they know" ["id"]=> string(9) "text_4042" ["value"]=> string(28) " Article Not Found" ["type"]=> string(8) "textarea" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["rows"]=> int(10) } } string(10) "rows="10" "

Comment: `$attr` is an array and you are trying to print it like `<?php echo ($attr); ?>`. Try replacing it with <?php echo ($attr['rows']); ?>

Comment: @b0ne thank you. It's solve the $attr, but still get error for $value.

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: @b0ne this value printed on my screen: array(6) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Subtitle for 404" ["desc"]=> string(33) "Enter some texts for the subtitle" ["id"]=> string(8) "text_404" ["value"]=> string(58) "This is subtitle for the 404. Insert from the option panel" ["type"]=> string(8) "textarea" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["rows"]=> int(10) } } string(10) "rows="10" "

Comment: @b0ne should I delete var_dump($value); and var_dump($attr);? and just change the <?php echo ($attr); ?> to <?php echo ($attr['rows']); ?>

Comment: Yeah you can delete them now. Are you getting any errors now?

Comment: Thank you @b0ne . It's look like work fine. Will let you know then.